# No funciona metodo post laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Estoy intentando agregar datos a mi *base de datos*; campo `nombre`, pero no me funciona.

He intentado con

```
echo "sdsdds";
```

Pero ni eso me muestra, también intenté con `all();` y tampoco funcionó cuando debería agregarse sin problemas y antes de eso funcionaba de maravilla

**vista**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('crear') }}">
    <input
        type="text"
        name="nombre"
        placeholder="Nombre"
        class="form-control mb-2"
    />
    <input
        type="text"
        name="descripcion"
        placeholder="Descripcion"
        class="form-control mb-2"
    />
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

**ruta**

```
Route::post('/','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@crear')->name('crear');
```

**controlador**

```
public function crear(Request $request) {

    // return $request->all();
    $notaNueva = new App\ejemplo;
    $notaNueva->nombre = $request->nombre;
    //$notaNueva->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $notaNueva->save();

    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Nota agregada');
}
```

Comment: En tu form has colocado type="POST"?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="{{ route('crear') }}"> asi lo tengo

Comment: con type tampoco, ademas no muestra ningun error

Comment: Te falta añadir esto antes del botón submit: @csrf

Comment: gracias, por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

falta la instrucción @csrf dentro de las etiquetas form, @csrf asegura la petición.

Comment: Esta respuesta estaría mucho mas completa si le das a OP un ejemplo de como debería quedar su código. ;)